# How to access smartphone data from PC without manually granting permission?

Tags: permissions, android, desktop-computer

My smartphone (Android 9.0 Pie) screen was broken so I wanted to get data from it. I connected it to my PC, but the problem is that I cannot give permission from smartphone to PC to access data because the whole screen is broken and I am not able to click a button to do it. Is there a solution to access smartphone data without manually granting permission?

USB Debugging is unfortunately disabled

Comment: `USB Debugging is unfortunately disabled` .. :( I sincerely doubt it at this point.  Depending on the model.. repairing your screen (yourself) isn't all THAT difficult. Bummer dude.  Good luck.

Comment: I came up with a simple idea to connect a smartphone to the monitor and mouse and try to give permission in this way.